# Call function when <audio> is at specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am currently doing some fun website, which requires audio cues (I assume that's the name?). I want the site to do something, when the song has been played for exactly X amount of time.

I can easily get the current time using `element.currentTime`, but I have no clue how to say: ***when element.currentTime == 5.2, runFunction()*** - If you know what I mean. Is there some kind of way this could be done? My current test code:

<----AUDIO WILL START PLAYING---->
http://jsfiddle.net/jfL4mcnh/

```
$("<audio id='audioElement'>").appendTo("body");
$("#audioElement").attr("src", "http://mp3ornot.com/songs/1B.mp3").attr("autoplay", "autoplay");

setInterval(function() {
    //for some reason, $("#audioElement").currentTime won't work, so we're going old fashion
    time = document.getElementById("audioElement").currentTime;
    console.log(time);
}, 1000);
```

Also, I forgot to say this, I cannot do a `setTimeout()` and hit at the exact moment I want in milliseconds, because the audio can take some extra time to load, while the actual code runs exactly when it has been "seen", if you know what I mean. So no countdown. I need to be exact here.

Answer (score 1):

If you need greater resolution than `ontimeupdate` provides, you can use a `setInterval` instead.

**Live Demo (sound and alert box only!):**

```js
$("<audio id='audioElement'>").appendTo("body");
$("#audioElement").attr("src", "http://mp3ornot.com/songs/1B.mp3").attr("autoplay", "autoplay");

var triggered = false;

var ael = document.getElementById("audioElement");
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(ael.currentTime);
    if (!triggered && ael.currentTime >= 5.2) {
        triggered = true;
        alert("5.2 seconds reached");
    }
    if (ael.ended) clearInterval(interval);
}, 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JSFiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfL4mcnh/15/

Comment: This is close to mine.. no? `ontimeupdate` should in theory be the same as `.bind("timeupdate")` yeah? I see that my timeupdate doesn't update instantly, so I can't make it fire at exactly like 5.25 seconds. It will increment like 0.888, 1.212, 1.559, and so on. It's not going 0.001, 0.002. Yours does the same :(

Comment: @Snorlax If you need better resolution, you can use `setInterval` instead of `ontimeupdate`. The best resolution I've gotten to work with it is about 50ms. I don't think there is a way to get perfect millisecond accuracy. See the edit to my answer above.

Comment: I suppose I could use setInterval, then stop the polling when the currentTime > 5.25, for instance. Then make it poll every 5-10 milliseconds. That shouldn't put much load on the client PC.. right?

Comment: The `setInterval` polling doesn't work any lower resolution than about 50 milliseconds - `currentTime` doesn't update that fast, so you will get duplicate `currentTime` values and the computer will just spin its wheels. But yes you can absolutely stop the polling after 5.25 seconds, just put the `clearInterval` call inside of the first `if` statement, and delete the second `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

See this [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfL4mcnh/4/)

I've added the following line to the JavaScript `setInterval()` function:

```
if (time > 5.2) {
    myFunction();
}
```

`myFunction()` does a `console.log`, which you'll see in the console.

The reason I used `>` rather than `===` is that the time reported is never precise due to fluctuations in processing. A  Boolean in the condition would solve this problem:

```
triggered = false;
if (time > 5.2 && !triggered) {
    triggered = true;
    myFunction();
}
```

Comment: That will not work. Read the last part of my question, which I just added because I forgot to say that. The audio file can take additional time to load

Comment: this isn't a countdown, it's polling periodically then responding once the audio playback gets to a set length of time, if the audio takes a while to load then it's be correspondingly longer before the current time is reported as 5.2 secs - I've simulated this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfL4mcnh/12/

Comment: Yeah but what happens if the audio file loads 3 seconds late, because the request is lagging behind? Then the Javascript will fire wrong :)

Comment: This answer causes the event to fire multiple times. The asker wants it to be called only once.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister actually I was dealing with that addition when more relevant comments were added to the answer that I prioritised - a `triggered` variable, such as in your answer, is a nice solution to this problem

Comment: @Snorlax this is a [closer simulation](http://jsfiddle.net/jfL4mcnh/16/). I've also tried throttling my bandwidth and it always appears at the same beat, 5.2 secs in ... I can find no evidence at MDN or W3C that the currentTime isn't anything other than the reported playback time, i.e. a freeze in audio playback would delay the event by the length of the freeze

Comment: @ToniLeigh So far polling every 10ms seems to work spot on. It's not utterly perfect as in "when-time-reaches-this-EXACT-time", but it works pretty damn well. Other thing I could do, is just pause the audio file, then play it and right after `.play()`, I can do a polling with `setTimeout()`

Comment: I need to do something similar to this, however I have an array of events that need to take place.  I am a bit confused how to sort through the list to determine which event should play for the current frame of the video.  Will someone please give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have done it myself.. It seems.

http://jsfiddle.net/jfL4mcnh/13/

```
$("#audioElement").bind("timeupdate", function() {
    var currentTime = parseInt(this.currentTime, 10);
    if(currentTime == 2) { 
        console.log("2 seconds in");
        $(this).unbind("timeupdate");
    }
});
```

You can bind `timeupdate` to it, then unbind it (apparently it runs the code 4 times, so I have to unbind it).

EDIT: Nope, it doesn't update fast enough to make it perfect on point. It increments each ~300ms it seems.

Comment: It runs the code 4 times because currentTime fires at `2.2`, `2.4`, `2.6`, etc. Instead of parsing the current time float as an int, please see my answer for a cleaner solution. Thanks!

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'll reply to yours now.

Comment: Another important thing to note is that this solution will fail if the browser stutters and doesn't register a `timeupdate` event during the 2nd second.